# Remote run of exec file stored locally

Tags: ssh

I want to launch an exec file stored locally on remote machine (with the same architecture) by SSH.

I have written an Applescript and I have exported this as "File Format: Application". So if I want to launch this app from the Terminal I must write the following command line:

```
/path-to-the-script-folder/MyAppleScript.app/contents/macOS
```

There isn't problem so far.

I want to launch this command remotely trough SSH on another Mac.
I have tried by the following command, but it doesn't work.

```
ssh hostname < /path-to-the-script-folder/MyAppleScript.app/contents/macOS
```

This is the error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

I don't have problem with SSH. The connection between two machine is established trough a RSA-key, without password. I don't want copy the exec file on remote.

Comment: Have you read the man page for ssh yet? Try searching for `pseudo-terminal`.

Comment: Indeed looks like a duplicate. Running SSH with the `-T` command-line flag should fix the issue.